# Multiple Load More OOB Button Sprig

Tags: twig, craftcms

I am trying to create multiple dynamic load more oob buttons using Sprig plugin in Craft CMS and they are appearing properly. But the issue comes up when **one button** is due to be swapped with the hidden one, it results to all the load more buttons disappearing.

Here is the for loop code that I have tested:

```
{% for city in cities %}
    {% set articleOffset = articleOffset ?? 0 %}
    {% set articlesQuery = cityArticles[loop.index0].offset(articleOffset).limit(articleLimit) %}
    {% set articles = articlesQuery.all() %}

    <div class="filtered-bookmark mb-5">
        <span> {{ city.title }}</span>
        <div class="row" id="container-{{ city.slug }}">
            {% for article in articles %}
                {% set featureImage = article.articleFeaturedImage.one().url ?? "" %}
                {% set categorySlug = article.channelsCategory.one().channel.one().slug %}

                <section class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-xl-4 mb-4">
                    {#article card template here#}
                </section>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        
        {% if articlesQuery.count() > articles|length + articleOffset %}
            <button id="{{city.slug}}-oob" sprig  
                s-val:articleOffset="{{ articleOffset + articleLimit }}" 
                s-target="#container-{{ city.slug }}" 
                s-select="#container-{{ city.slug }} section"
                s-swap="beforeend"
                {{ sprig.trigger == city.slug ~ '-oob' ? 's-swap-oob="true"' }}> View More </button>
        {% else %}
            <button id="{{ city.slug }}-oob" s-swap-oob="true" style="display: none"></button>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked the question on PutYourLightsOn's Sprig GitHub and got a response. This did the trick:

```
<button id="{{ city.slug }}-oob" {{ sprig.trigger == city.slug ~ '-oob' ? 's-swap-oob="true"' }} style="display: none"></button>
```

GitHub link for reference:
https://github.com/putyourlightson/craft-sprig/issues/247